# What is the difference between std::string (*)[96][60] and std::string* [96][60]?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have multiple two-dimensional 96-by-60 `std::string` arrays. I'm trying to make a pointer that can point to one of these arrays.

The arrays look something like this:

```
std::string array1[96][60];
std::string array2[96][60];
```

The pointer I made looks like this:

```
std::string *ptr_to_array[96][60];
```

Everything compiles if I just declare the pointer. But when I try to do the following

```
ptr_to_array = &array1;
```

I get this error:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘std::string (*)[96][60]’ to ‘std::string* [96][60]’
```

To me, it appears both types are the same.

Also, from what I've read on this subject, lots of people recommend using `std::array`. I would, but it seems like an even bigger problem than this when trying to deal with multidimensional `std::array`s. I'd prefer to just fix my `std::string` arrays, but would it be better or easier to just switch to `std::array`?

Comment: `std::string (*)[96][60]` is a pointer to an array of strings. `std::string* [96][60]` is an array of pointers to string. Make it `std::string (*ptr_to_array)[96][60];`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So how can should I write the line `ptr_to_array = &array1;`? I think I have to change `&array1` somehow.

Comment: No, you have to change `ptr_to_array` somehow.

Comment: And if you just use `std::unique_ptr<std::array<std::array<std::string, 96>, 60>>` it would be both readable and easier to manage.

Comment: @MSalters Why would one want to introduce a heap allocation where there was none before?

Comment: Okay, I'll probably just switch over to `std::array` since it seems to have less issues with pointers than arrays do (in C++, at least).

Comment: If you have a C++11 compiler you can simply do `auto ptr_to_array = &array1;` without having to mess with pointer to array syntax.

Comment: @Praetorian I will probably use that, but I want to be sure that `&array1` is a pointer to a two-dimensional array of strings, and *not* a two-dimensional array of string pointers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Because almost 6000 strings is a pretty large chunk of memory, and besides, it's quite possible those 6000 strings do heap allocations themselves. One extra is negligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
std::string *ptr_to_array[96][60];
```

is not a declaration of a pointer. It is a declaration of a 2D array of pointers to objects of type `std::string`.

If you want to use expression

```
&array1
```

and assign it to a pointer then the pointer has to be defined like

```
std::string ( *ptr_to_array )[96][60];
ptr_to_array  = &array1;
```

But I suspect that actually you need a pointer to the first element of the array. In this case the declaration will look like

```
std::string ( *ptr_to_array )[60];
ptr_to_array  = array1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The types are *not* the same. `std::string* [96][60]` is a 2D array of pointers. `std::string (*)[96][60]` is a pointer to a 2D array.

- Taking description literally, you need something along the lines of

  ```
  std::string (*ptr_to_array)[96][60];
  ptr_to_array = &array1;
  ```

  Later you can access the array through the pointer as

  ```
  (*ptr_to_array)[i][j];
  ```

  In this case you literally declare `ptr_to_array` as a pointer to a 2D array.
- Alternatively, you can do

  ```
  std::string (*ptr_to_array)[60];
  ptr_to_array = array1;
  ```

  and later access it as

  ```
  ptr_to_array[i][j];
  ```

The former variant will enforce full match of both array sizes when intializing the pointer. The latter variant ignores the first array size.

- You can also use a reference to an array in the first variant

  ```
  std::string (&ref_to_array)[96][60] = array1;
  ```

  which will preserve the "natural" array access syntax

  ```
  ref_to_array[i][j];
  ```

  But references have to be initialized at the point of declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you question right, this is what you are looking for right?

```
std::string array1[3][3];
std::string array2[3][3];
auto* test = &array1;

std::cout << test[0] << std::endl;

test = &array2;

std::cout << test[0] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Maybe. I'm afraid that `&array1` is a two-dimensional array of pointers to strings, which is NOT what I want. I want a pointer to a two-dimensional array of strings. I'm not entirely sure which one of these `&array1` evaluates to.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'll try it out and let you guys know. But should I use `auto* ptr` like this guy said, or should I use `auto ptr` like someone up above said?

Comment: @gragas `auto ptr` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want a pointer that you can index in the same way as the original array:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    string array1[96][60] = {{"Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"}};
    string array2[96][60];

    string (*p)[60] = array1;

    cout << array1[0][2] << endl;
    cout << p[0][2] << endl;
}
```

---

Instead of battling the C syntax directly like above, you can use `typedef` or C++11 `using` to define names for types, which makes things more clear:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    using String_row    = string[60];
    using String_matrix = String_row[96];

    String_matrix array1 = {{"Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"}};
    String_matrix array2;

    String_row* p = array1;

    String_matrix* pa = &array1;

    cout << array1[0][2] << endl;
    cout << p[0][2] << endl;
    cout << (*pa)[0][2] << endl;
}
```

---

If you really want a pointer *to the array itself*, not a nicely indexable pointer to the first item of the array, then at the C syntax level it would go like

```
string (*pa)[96][60] = &array1;
```

and you'd use it like

```
cout << (*pa)[0][2] << endl;
```

It's the same memory address as the pointer-to-first-item, but of slightly different type.

---

All that said, I recommend defining or using a matrix class based on `std::vector` as storage provider, instead of directly using raw arrays.